# Is it possible to set the Unity Launcher to a nice solid color?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, colors

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/196/screenshotfrom201204280.png/

Is it possible to get the Unity Launcher, dash, HUD etc to use a nice solid color? The best way would be to extend the panel theme all around the screen.

This is not possible with MyUnity, there will always be some transparancy as far as I can tell from my trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that trying `MyUbuntu` has some effects of those things as you have stated (which can easily be found in the ubuntu software center), but you can also try `Compiz Settings` the settings of which I refer to for this one would be under the unity settings(which can also be found in the ubuntu software center).

Be careful though, some of the settings are still "experimental" so they can mess up your system.

=) gl

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the transparency of the DASH display.

The following worked for me:
Using 'MyUnity', change the color under 'launcher' to black [000000] by clicking on the color bar.

Until opaque is an option, this is the best work-around I tried.